# Multiple stylesheets issue using React

Tags: css, styles, stylesheet, react-css-modules

I am new to react, I have an issue on how to maintain stylesheets in react.
**For Eg:** 
If I have **box structures** in different components with the **same class names** which are import to **Page-A** & **Page-B**, 
 I maintained different stylesheets & appended those to their respective pages. 
If I change the style properties for **Page-B** in respective stylesheet using the same class name, changes are reflecting in both the **Page-A** & **Page-B** pages, which is suppose to reflect in **Page-B** only. 
Please help to solve this.

**Page-A**
`<div class="wrapper">Headline<div>`
`.wrapper{background:red; width:200px; height:200px;}`
**Page-B**
`<div class="wrapper">Headline<div>`
`.wrapper{background:black; width:400px; height:400px;}`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import NavbarafterLogin from './NavigationBar/navbarafterlogin';
import '../../Css/afterlogins.css';

class Home extends Component {   
render() {
    return (            
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <NavbarafterLogin/>
            <div class="body-wrapper">
                <div class="container">                        
                    <ViewProfile/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}
 export default Home;
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import NavbarBeforeLogin from './NavigationBar/navbarbeforelogin';
import '../../Css/beforelogins.css';

class Index extends Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <NavbarBeforeLogin />
            <div class="body-wrapper clearfix">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <div class="banner-sec">
                        <div class="jumbotron">
                            <div class="container">
                                <h1>Submit <strong>Profile</strong></h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}
 export default Index;
```

Comment: can you add more details about how you import your stylesheets in both ?

Comment: @AymanMorsy , Thanks for the quick response, I just updated can u plz check.

Comment: You can try css in js https://cssinjs.org/?v=v10.1.1 it makes sure what render is what you see